# Finding given objects under both a polygon and a buffer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap

I'm a bit new to ArcGis 10.1, but know the basics.

I have two source layers, a polygon and a huge buffer. The polygon contains some of that buffer, but not all of it. There are numerous points inside that polygon (and outside), and I want to know how many of them are inside both the polygon AND the buffer.

Select by location only allows me to ask for one of the source layers, not both at the same time.  Any ideas of how to proceed ?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to create new features, but just get a fast count, you *can* perform Select By Location twice.

The trick is to use a different Selection Method the second time: **select from the currently selected features in**.

[image]

In other words, first Select By Location to find what intersects your polygon (using the regular "select features from" selection method), then Select By Location with to find what also intersects the buffer (using "select from the currently selected features in").

Answer (score 1):

You would need to run [Intersect](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Intersect/00080000000p000000/) GP tool first to get a geometry of the intersection between the polygon and the buffered zone. When you got this, you can run [Spatial Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000q000000) GP tool and find out how many points are located within this intersection area by looking into the Count column in the result feature class.

Comment: Or you could again Intersect using the points and the previous intersect result, or with an Advanced License you could just intersect all three to start with - the results will be a point layer with only those in the area of both polygons. Though if you just want a count, performing a selection on a selection per Erica's answer would be simpler/faster.